# GPIO modes without breaking serial

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, serial

I am using and Adafruit BNO055 IMU and using their provided modules to read the data, i have been able to do so.  However i want to be able to turn some of the GPIO pins to high as i want to control stuff from this data, to do that in python you normally use import RPi as GPIO ect.  However doing this before the initialisation of the IMU means that the GPIOs aren't available to use for the serial connection (pin 18 , Rx and Tx) and if you do it after you get an error 'GPIO mode already set' however try as i might i can see it being set to any mode in the module.  How can i get past this?

Comment: Your question is vague. You haven't listed any code or what you have tried. I haven't any idea what a "BNO055 IMU" is or how it is connected - provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different library to control the GPIO?

I don't see why Adafruit should care what other libraries are doing.

E.g. try my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) or wiringPi etc.

Comment: the serial connection includes a GPIO pin and if i change to GPIO library it doesn't connect to the sensor.  i have had a look at the module for the sensor at it does import adafruits own GPIO library, i now need to find out how to use this library and it isn't that simple (for me any way)